# Group only specific values and get min and max dates

Tags: sql, max, min

Hello and thank you in advance, not sure my title will suffice but hoping the image with the desired output will help. Essentially, the data where eventtype=2 needs to be grouped by ID. Once grouped, I still need to concatenate the Min(eventdate) and max(eventdate).

The First image is just the simple select statment(select * from TABLE).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT __DisplayName,
       EventDate,
       RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEADD(HOUR, -5 , EventDate), 100),7)
        + ' to ' + 
       RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20), DATEADD(HOUR, -5 , EndDate), 100),7),
       location,
       __EventType
  FROM (SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                 ( PARTITION BY Id 
                       ORDER BY eventdate asc
                 ) AS ROWNUM
          FROM TABLE
       ) x 
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
   AND __ApprovalStatus = 'Approved' 
   AND __EventType not in ('1','-1');
```

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't ID 10 group Nov 7 - Nov 8?  Could you not just use `min` and `max`?

Comment: Would you mind specifying the RDBMS? It looks like SQL Server to me, but can't be absolutely certain.

Comment: If your first screenshot is just `select * from yourtable`, can you not just use `select id, eventtitle, eventtime, location, eventtype, min(eventdate), max(eventdate) from yourtable group by id, eventtitle, eventtime, location, eventtype`?  Easy enough to concatonate the min and max in a single column if you need to...

Comment: Excellent point. Now that you say that how can I group by ID and when event type = -2 ?  That is the only event type I need to be "Truncated" to one row.

Comment: Hi David, your are correct, this is sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. YOu led me to the right answer. SO what I did is essentially union two queries. One that gets all data where eventtype is not in -1,1, and -2 and then another query that essentially concatenates the min and max but only where event type = -2

```
(Select  __DisplayName, cast(min(EventDate)as varchar) Eventdate from TABLE WHERE __ApprovalStatus = 'Approved' and __EventType not in ('1','-1','-2')
group by ID, __DisplayName
Union ALL
Select  __DisplayName, 
cast(min(EventDate)as varchar) + ' - ' +  cast(max(EventDate) as varchar) Eventdate     from TABLE WHERE    __ApprovalStatus = 'Approved' and __EventType = -2     group by ID, __DisplayName)
order by Eventdate
```